# Active electric motor for on specify voltage

Tags: motor, diodes, diy

Is it possible to power on electric motor ( a little ) only when the input voltage is 1V by example.

The electric motor is supply by another source (9V by example)

With diode?? Or something else?

I'm a very beginner on electronics, please excuse my English, I'm French.

Logic :

- Input 0v = Do nothing
- Input 1V = Power On electronic motor with 9V supply
- When if the voltage is less then 1V power off motor.

Thanks your helps.
Regards

In Summary:

Is it possible to control a 9V DC motor by using only a 1V logic input; provided that the DC Motor is supplied with 9 volts.

Comment: You want to draw the power from the 1V logic, or do you want to control some other power source with the 1V? The 1V logic won't be able to supply enough current for the motor to work, it would try to draw current but the rest of the circuit won't be able to handle that kind of current. Therefore the source of the logic 1V will probably go up in smoke!!

Comment: I do a reply below

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to turn on a 9 V motor from a 0-1 V control signal.

One way is to use a NPN low side switch:

[image]

You didn't say how much current the motor draws, but let's say 500 mA, and that the transistor can be counted on to have a gain of 50.  That means you need at least 10 mA base current.  Figure the worst case B-E voltage drop is 750 mV, which leaves 250 mV across R1.  (250 mV)/(10 mA) = 25 Ω, which is the maximum allowed base resistor. 20 Ω might be a good value in that case.

### Added:

You have now changed the question so that you want a control signal threshold to be 500 mV to decide whether the motor should be on or not.

This can no longer be done with the circuit above, which was for the spec of 1 V control signal to turn on the motor.  With such a low threshold, you should use a comparator, which can then drive a transistor to turn on the motor.  You will have to provide the 500 mV threshold voltage to one input of the comparator, and the control signal to the other input.  If the 9 V supply is stable, you can derive the 500 mV reference from it with a resistor divider.  Otherwise, you can use the 9 V supply to power a regulated reference that ultimately produces 500 mV.

As for controlling the motor from a 3.5 mm jack, you can use any connector you like.  If you want to drive the motor from a audio signal above some amplitude, then that is again a totally different question.  I'm not going to keep chasing a changing spec.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's possible to add 2nd motor and do this input < 0.5V turn on motor1 >; if  input > 0.5V turn on motor2? What is piece to change the active voltage (1V in my first question). I just want control motor via jack 3.5mm on my Android. Thanks again